# jQuery action only once / custom URLs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very basic jQuery script that slides a title from bottom to top after the page loads. The problem I'm having now is that I need to make this title to only slide if the user is on the 'main page'. If the user then clicks on any sub-pages I need the title to remain to the top of the page.

Example: wordpress website with a few pages on which I have galleries. When a user enters a page -> animate title. When the user is browsing the gallery -> static title.

This is the jQuery script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery(".animate").addClass("move"); 
});
```

You can see the website in question [here](http://www.noahd.net/demo-upwall/residential/rooftop-garden/).

// **later edit:** Thanks everyone for helping! I forgot to mention that I have multiple URLs, there are multiple pages. Is there a way I can get the "current URL" of the page and then append to it the extra bit which will always be the same i.e. `/?pid=xx` ?

Example: I need to animate the title on pages with this format:

`mywebpage/custom_name/`

Then, on pages with this format, I need to keep the title static:

`mywebpage/custom_name/?pid=xx`

Following the answers bellow I made this script:

```
if(window.location.href == 'http://www.noahd.net/demo-upwall/residential/rooftop-garden/'){
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery(".animate").addClass("move"); 
    });
} else {
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery(".portfolio-title-wrap").removeClass("animate").addClass("top"); 
    }); 
}
```

This script works only for the `/residential/rooftop-garden/` page. Under `residential` I have another 10 pages. And then I have another 6 pages starting from root, like `/commercial/` or `/objects` which also have 6-10 sub-pages.

How can I adapt the above script to work on those pages and sub-pages but not on the sub-sub-pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decide behavior of your page based on url.

code:

```
if(window.location.href== mainapplicationurl){

    // slide code
}
else{
      // put title on top

}
```

After edit of question. you can decide pages based of count of '/' in url( will work only if url format is consistent).

```
var count = window.location.href.split("/").length;
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   if( count < 7 ){        
        jQuery(".animate").addClass("move"); 
   } else {        
        jQuery(".portfolio-title-wrap").removeClass("animate").addClass("top"); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! I've updated the question with more information.

Comment: Thanks, I replaced the `/` with `?` to work on my case. I didn't had any extra `/` just one `?` from `/?pid=xx`. Thanks again for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress labels pages with unique classes so you can target an specific page like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".page-id-32 .animate").addClass("move"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it different ways. For example you can load your slide title stuff only when you are on specific page using wordpress conditions.

Or you can do what you want from client-side. For example, your pages have different title tags, and main page has - Upwall Studio and you can check:

```
if ($('title').text() === 'Upwall Studio') {
  //slide youre title here
}
```

Or you can check if user on a specific url via window.location.href:

```
if (window.location.href === 'http://www.noahd.net/demo-upwall/') {
  //slide youre title here
}
```